# Xamarin Android Java Binding: Missing class (XMLReader)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding, java-binding

I'm facing some warnings nearly always when I'm on a Xamarin.Android project, and using a Java Binding Library. I obtain the following warnings:

```
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseBundleExtras in managed type Android.Content.Res.Resources.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXmlInner in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXmlInner in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type 
System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseIntent in managed type Android.Content.Intent.
7>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ReadFromXml in managed type Android.Content.IntentFilter.
```

My first thought was that it was missing the System.XML.XMLReader NuGet dependency, but it had no sense. I added the dependency, and didn't work.

Later, viewing the code (e.g. [android.content.Intent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/core/java/android/content/Intent.java)), I realized that somehow it's getting wrong when resolving the required class. It's not the System.XML .Net framework one, but XMLReader class from Android Framework.

Any idea on pointing the binding proccess to the right direction, telling explicitely what class to pick? Some metadata.xml rule? Thanks

EDIT: I'm trying with this:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='android.content.res']/class[@name='Resources']/method[@name='parseBundleExtras']/parameter[0]"
    name="type">android.content.res.XmlResourceParser</attr>
```

as can be seen [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#1995), but parser is not finding anything, even using a less fine-grained query:

```
Metadata.xml(15, 4) warning BG8A04: <attr path="/api/package[@name='android.content.res']/class[@name='Resources']"/> matched no nodes. Seems that I can't make that metadata changes in Android framework directly?
```

Comment: You could try to add `<attr 
path="/api/package[@name='org.apache.http.cookie']/class[@name='CookiePathComparer']/implements[@name='java.util.Comparator']" 
name="name">java.util.Comparator<org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie></attr> ` in metadata.  http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/JAR-Binding-problems-after-updating-to-4-6-td5712947.html

Comment: @Billy excuse me, but I can't understand where you want to achieve exactly. Perhaps change the path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get correct assemblies

1. In *Solution Explorer* right-click ***References***
2. Select ***Add References...***
3. Select ***Assemblies*** tab

All you need is ***System.Xml***

1. Scroll down and find ***System.Xml*** in *Assemblies* tab
2. Select it
3. Press ***Ok*** button

Most common path to the assembly relatively from Visual Studio folder:

```
...\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
```

<sub>If it shows multiple assemblies with same name, don't worry, you can pick any of it. Don't use GAC or nuget package. Always look for Assemblies corresponding to your project type which is always t the *Assemblies tab* in *Preference Manager*.</sub>

<sub>Before attempting to build after the fix, ***clean*** the project or do a ***clean build***.</sub>